# Template recursion doesn't stop

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create template recursion which let me create sequence<0,1,2,3,4> by using make_sequence<4>  but it seems that recursion not stops on specialization and just keep running until stackoverfolw.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

template <std::size_t... Indices>
struct sequence {};




template<std:: size_t N, std::size_t ... Indices>
struct make_sequenceAppend{
        using type = typename make_sequenceAppend<N-1, N, Indices...>::type;
};

template<std:: size_t , std::size_t ... Indices>
struct make_sequenceAppend<0ul, Indices...>{
        using type =  typename sequence< Indices...>::type;

};

template <std::size_t N>
struct make_sequence{

        using type = typename make_sequenceAppend<N-1, N>::type;

};


int main()
{
  make_sequence<4>();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: > *warning: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used.* (about `template<std:: size_t , std::size_t ... Indices>
struct make_sequenceAppend<0ul, Indices...>`)

Comment: please switch on your compiler warnings

Answer (score 5):

Your specialization's declaration is wrong. It should be:

```
template<std::size_t ... Indices>
struct make_sequenceAppend<0ul, Indices...>{
```

Additionally, `sequence< Indices...>::type` does not exist. Your complete specialization should probably be:

```
template<std::size_t ... Indices>
struct make_sequenceAppend<0ul, Indices...>{
        using type =  sequence< Indices...>;

};
```

There's also a missing semicolon in your `main()`, but that's beside the point...